# numpy - round columns to closest decimal value

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of floats of shape `(N,3)`. I would like to round the two first columns to the closest decimal values varing from 1 to 0 which is derived from a parameter.

I have already a solution, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient or "numpy" way to achieve it.

For istance:

```
import numpy as np

def round_to(arr, round_to):
  col_1_rounded = np.round(arr[:,0] / round_to) * round_to
  col_2_rounded = np.round(arr[:,1] / round_to) * round_to
  return np.vstack((col_1_rounded, col_2_rounded, arr[:,2])).transpose()

arr = np.array((
        (0.24, 1.26, 45.0),
        (0.76, 1.43, 23.0),
        (2.923, 2.22, 29.0),
        (33.1202, 2.1, 5.0),
        (2.01, 2.55, 41.0)
       ))

print(round_to(arr, 0.1))
>>>[[ 0.2  1.2 45. ]
   [ 0.8  1.4 23. ]
   [ 2.9  2.2 29. ]
   [33.1  2.1  5. ]
   [ 2.   2.5 41. ]]

print(round_to(arr, 0.5))
>>>[[ 0.   1.  45. ]
   [ 1.   1.5 23. ]
   [ 3.   2.  29. ]
   [33.   2.   5. ]
   [ 2.   2.5 41. ]]
```

**Note:**

I have found other similar rounding functions on SO using instead `round(value * round_to) / round_to` but inversing the `/` and `*` operators does not return the correct results with my demo data. Why?

```
def round_to(arr, round_to):
  col_1_rounded = np.round(arr[:,0] * round_to) / round_to
  col_2_rounded = np.round(arr[:,1] * round_to) / round_to
  return np.vstack((col_1_rounded, col_2_rounded, arr[:,2])).transpose()

arr = np.array((
    (0.24, 1.26, 45.0),
    (0.76, 1.43, 23.0),
    (2.923, 2.22, 29.0),
    (33.1202, 2.1, 5.0),
    (2.01, 2.55, 41.0)
   ))

print(round_to(arr, 0.5))
>>>[[ 0.  2. 45.]
    [ 0.  2. 23.]
    [ 2.  2. 29.]
    [34.  2.  5.]
    [ 2.  2. 41.]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your "Note" is saying.  It looks to me like that is exactly the code you are using.  You would swap `*` and `/` if you were specifying `round_to` as `10` instead of `0.1`, which cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Comment: And you can do that in one step as `arr[:,0:2] = np.round(arr[:,0:2]...`, assuming you want to modify in place.

Comment: @TimRoberts the rounding result is different when you change the order of the * and / operators. See my edit.

Comment: Of course it does.  As I said, if you reverse the order of the operators, you have to invert the multiplier.  In your example, use `2` instead of `0.5`.  You're rounding to the nearest 1/X, not to X.

Answer (score 1):

numpy provides the around function that allows to enter the amount of decimals for rounding. With the example given :

```
arr = np.array((
        (0.24, 1.26, 45.0),
        (0.76, 1.43, 23.0),
        (2.923, 2.22, 29.0),
        (33.1202, 2.1, 5.0),
        (2.01, 2.55, 41.0)
       ))
arr[:,0:2] = np.around(arr[:,0:2],1)
```

Gives the right output:

```
array([[ 0.2,  1.3, 45. ],
       [ 0.8,  1.4, 23. ],
       [ 2.9,  2.2, 29. ],
       [33.1,  2.1,  5. ],
       [ 2. ,  2.6, 41. ]])
```

Comment: How would you round to 0.5 with np.around?

Comment: I would do it similar to what you did i.e. 
arr[:,0:2] = np.around(2*arr[:,0:2],0)/2